# Delimiters -- appropriate usage

Tags: amsmath, delimiters

What is the appropriate LaTeX when I do not want a closing right bracket? Alternatively, should I setup the left bracket differently?

```
\begin{align*}
  r_{sj} &= 
  \left\{ \begin{array}{lc} 
     1 & \text{if $Y_j$ is observed in $s$} \\
     0 & \text{if $Y_j$ is missing in $s$} 
  \end{array} \right
\end{align*}
```

Here, I do not wish to have `\right\}` in the text.

But I get a missing delimiter error on compiling

Comment: If you don't want a closing "fence" symbol -- curly brace, square bracket, round parenthesis, angle bracket, vertical bar, whatever --  simply write `\right.` (note the "dot" after `\right`). As you've observed, `\right` by itself throws a syntax error.

Comment: in general you can use `.` but `amsmath` has a specific `cases` environment to produce this kind of display, which adds the `{` automatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this kind of thing there is the `cases` environment.  If the second columns primarily consists of text, you might want to use `cases*` from `mathtools`.  If you had some other construction, where `cases` does not apply, you can insert an “empty” delimiter using `.` as in `\right.`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% load amsmath

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  r_{sj} = 
  \begin{cases*}
     1 & if $Y_j$ is observed in $s$ \\
     0 & if $Y_j$ is missing in $s$ \\
  \end{cases*}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For other constructions, there's also the solution of the `empheq` package (which loads `mathtools`) and its eponymous environment.